# php date() showing wrong day

Tags: php, date, time

Noticed that dates were off on a page and I can't figure out why.

Just doing this simple code

```
echo date("F m, Y: h:iA e");
```

Returns this:

```
July 07, 2013: 09:47PM America/New_York
```

The time is correct, the date is obviously behind (today being the 25th).

I checked the time on server

```
root@srv449 [~]# date
Thu Jul 25 21:48:42 EDT 2013
```

Any tips on where this could be thrown off? What's REALLY confusing me is that other pages where we use dates seem to be ok.

Also, doing

```
echo time();
```

returns

```
1374803608
```

which seems correct.

Comment: You have read the manual on [`date()`](http://php.net/date), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m` is month (which is `7` for July).

You want `d` (leading zeros) or `j` (without leading zeros):

```
echo date("F j, Y: h:iA e");
```

See [`date()` format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more.

Comment: Oh god. I've disgraced my family. Thank you for catching that. Hahah.

Answer (score 2):

You are outputing the month as the day here:

```
echo date("F m, Y: h:iA e");
```

It needs to be:

```
echo date("F d, Y: h:iA e");
```